# why does my flowchart seem different from exercise?

Tags: c

[image]

I have just study about flowchart for 2-3h and i am not sure that my flowchart are correct with the code that on the right side .

Please help me,I feel very stress i dont know if it correct or incorrect

Comment: `num * (num + 1)/2` can overflow `int` math.  Flowchart does not imply `int` or a range limit.  I'd expect `sum` to be a type twice as wide as `num`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica They're supposed to be creating the flowchart from the code, not the other way around. How would you express this UB in the flowchart?

Comment: @Barmar A arrow to a [Good & Plenty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_%26_Plenty) with UB in it.  How would you express this UB in the flowchart?

Answer (score 1):

```
int num, sum = 0;
```

only initializes `sum`. It doesn't do

```
SET num = 0
```

Also,

```
#include int main() {
```

is nonsense. `#include` should be followed by a header name, like

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Are you sure you copied that to the question properly?

Comment: oh my bad i forget to check the code does my flowchart correct with the code ?